# Filter results for Django paginator in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-generic-views, paginator

I'm filtering out results from my page_obj in a generic view to only show entries published in the same language as the languge currently set by django-cms (http://www.django-cms.org/en/documentation/2.0/i18n/).

This works fine, but adding in support for Django pagination (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/pagination/) causes the filtered results to still be counted. So, for example when there are three results in English, from a total of ten results and pagination is set to 2, I'll get 5 result pages, most of which are of course blank becuse the filtering of the remaining seven is done in the template.

Can I amend Django Paginator to work with the filter in the template using a template tag, or do I have to rebuild my views? If so, how do I go about doing that?

The relevant code:

**managers.py**

```
def update_queryset(view, queryset, queryset_parameter='queryset'):
    '''Decorator around views based on a queryset passed in parameter, which will force the update of the queryset before executing the view.
    Related to issue: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8378'''
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        #Regenerate the queryset before passing it to the view.
        kwargs[queryset_parameter] = queryset()
        return view(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap
```

**views/entries.py**

```
from django.views.generic.list_detail import object_list
from cmsplugin_publisher.models import Entry
from cmsplugin_publisher.managers import update_queryset

entry_index = update_queryset(object_list, Entry.published.all)
```

**urls/entries.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from cmsplugin_publisher.models import Entry
from cmsplugin_publisher.settings import PAGINATION, ALLOW_EMPTY, ALLOW_FUTURE

entry_conf_list = {'queryset': Entry.published.all(), 'paginate_by': PAGINATION}

entry_conf = { 'queryset': Entry.published.all(),}

entry_conf_detail = entry_conf.copy()
entry_conf_detail['queryset'] = Entry.objects.all()

urlpatterns = patterns('cmsplugin_publisher.views.entries',
    url(r'^$', 'entry_index', entry_conf_list, name='cmsplugin_publisher_entry_archive_index'),
    url(r'^(?P<page>[0-9]+)/$', 'entry_index', entry_conf_list, name='cmsplugin_publisher_entry_archive_index_paginated'),
)

urlpatterns += patterns('django.views.generic.list_detail',
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'object_detail', entry_conf_detail, name='cmsplugin_publisher_entry_detail'),
)
```

**in entry_list.html**

```
{% block content %}
    {% for object in object_list %}
      {% ifequal object.language current_language %}
        ..
      {% endifequal %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if is_paginated %}
    <ul id="pagination">
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        {% ifnotequal page_obj.start_index 1 %}<li><a href="../" title="{% trans 'View Latest Entries' %}">{% trans 'Latest Entries' %}</a></li>{% endifnotequal %}
        {% ifequal page_obj.previous_page_number 1 %}{% endifequal %}
        {% ifnotequal page_obj.previous_page_number 1 %}
            <li><a href="../{{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}/" title="{% trans 'View Earlier Entries' %}">{% trans 'Earlier Entries' %}</a></li>
        {% endifnotequal %}
    {% else%}
    {% endif %}
    <li>{% trans 'Page' %} {{ page_obj.start_index }} {% trans 'of' %} {{ paginator.num_pages }} {% trans 'Entries' %}</li>
    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
        {% ifnotequal page_obj.start_index 1 %}
            <li><a href="../{{ page_obj.next_page_number }}/" title="{% trans 'View Older Entries' %}">{% trans 'Older Entries' %}</a></li>
        {% endifnotequal %}
        {% ifequal page_obj.start_index 1 %}
        <li><a href="{{ page_obj.next_page_number }}/" title="{% trans 'View Older Entries' %}">{% trans 'Older Entries' %}</a></li>
        {% endifequal %}
    {% else%}
    {% endif %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

I'd appreciate any light you guys can throw on the best solution here.

Comment: why ain't you using filter with the query itself and not in the templates? Django creates pagination links based on the query results which you use in templates, changing them in template does not seem to be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The soultion, ultimately, was to rebuild the views. Extensive rebuilding required in this case.

Moral of the sory: don't filter in templates!